# MYSQL query to get rows from same table where specific value is different

Tags: mysql

I am not very good in SQL-Queries and got stuck with a query.

I have the following (simplified) table structure:

```
hash  state  group
x123    1     41
x456    2     44
x123    3     41
x456    2     44
x123    2     42
...    ...   ...
```

The hash is an identifier for a person which can be part of one or more groups.

I want to get all rows of persons wich are in more than one group. So from my example I would get all three rows of the person with the hash "x123", but none from the person with the hash "x456".

It would be nice, if anyone could help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: mysql version ?

Comment: @Barmar that duplicate matches the question perfectly, but didn't have a window function answer, so I added one

Comment: Yeah, lots of canonical dups need to be updated with window function solutions.

Comment: Ah I did not find that question, thanks. The most upvoted example does not work for me. It gives me all rows, dont know why. M Khalid Junaids answer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS` with some aggregate condition

```
select *
from users u
where exists (
  select 1
  from users
  where hash= u.hash
  having count(distinct `group`) > 1
)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c99244/14)

Comment: @frankvanlampe [How to say thanks on SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/#:~:text=On%20the%20left%20of%20the,thanks%20to%20the%20post%2Dauthor.) please have a look or mark the asnwer as accepted